# Write to database from case results

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to update a databased based upon results from a case, however my "If" statement doesn't seem to pull information from the right table.

```
declare @dt datetime 
set @dt = GETDATE()
select
Ugenummer = datepart(wk, @dt) - datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @dt), 0)) + 1,
case when (datepart(wk, @dt) - datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @dt), 0)) + 1) % 2 = 1
     then 'ulige' else 'lige' end Ugelighed;
```

The above code gets the weeknumber (ugenummer) and determines whether it's odd or even (Ulige/lige)

```
 IF Ugelighed = ulige and datepart(dw,@dt) = 1
THEN 
    UPDATE laeger
    SET Antal=1
    WHERE Navn=Lægenavn
```

I would like to use the information from the first code to update a database in a SQL 2008 server

Comment: Don't just throw the code here. Please explain what it does, and how it does not work

Comment: You are using SQL Server? What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using Ugenummer so I edited it out. Also created a variable for Ugelighed, you forgot to create one:

```
declare @dt datetime 
set @dt = GETDATE()
declare @Ugelighed VARCHAR(5);
select
@Ugelighed=case when (datepart(wk, @dt) - datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @dt), 0)) + 1) % 2 = 1
     then 'ulige' else 'lige' end;
```

In the following statements I used variable `@Ugelighed` to compare to `ulige` however it is a `VARCHAR` so you need to enclose it in single quotes (`''`). Same for `Lægenavn`, it is a `VARCHAR` so enclose it in single quotes:

```
IF @Ugelighed = 'ulige' and datepart(dw,@dt) = 1
    UPDATE laeger
    SET Antal=1
    WHERE Navn='Lægenavn'
```

Personally I would have created a `BIT` field for `@Ugelighed` since even/odd can be captured as a simple boolean rather than text.

Comment: The first part of the code works now! (Wasn't sure how to assign a case to a variable) But the second part, where I want to update a table still doesn't work.

It returns the error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Comment: @Mclovin Oops, the `THEN` is not used in `IF/ELSE` statements. Updated my answer. Too fast in my copy/pasting.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it functions as intended